# Duplicate titles

Tags: discussion

Look at these two questions, [awk split one column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482372/awk-split-one-column-into-multiple-columns) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484904/awk-split-one-column-into-multiple-columns . How in the world, SO allows two same titles with exact characters?

Comment: the titles can be padded with space, these will get trimmed out when displaying, but prevent the duplicate title check from triggering. Why? no idea, but it works

Comment: So the `dupe title check script` needs to be moved down a notch to after the `trim spaces` script.

Comment: Hmmm, the title check may take into account the dominant tag.  Open both links and look at the page title.  One is prefixed with Bash, the other Awk.