# Were these two questions with duplicate titles 'grandfathered' in?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I know that when a user asks a question, they cannot ask one with an existing title, but how many scenarios does that check against?

I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274954/duplicate-titles) question regarding duplicate titles, which appears to be caused by spaces in one of the titles, but there's no word on whether or not it has been fixed.

An example I found today was two questions that had the same title, but had different case:

- [SQL Query to find Nth highest salary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070757/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary)
- [SQL query to find Nth highest salary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492357/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary)

Should this be allowed? I don't know when the duplicate title check went into effect, so it is possible these two questions have been grandfathered in.

Are there other checks that need to be made when considering duplicate titles? Were these made prior to the duplicate check?

---

I have found a couple examples where questions with duplicate titles exist. 
Today, after a MySQL question was closed, I saw this redundant list of possible helpful questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061604/mysql-query-to-find-out-nth-highest-salary).

Comment: DId you really print screen the "relevant questions", so we cannot actually access the links? :|

Comment: @amit sorry, lemme grab that haha.

Comment: There's also [SQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771984/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-a-salary-table) and [SQL query to find Nth highest salary from a salary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850034/sql-query-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-a-salary-table), which don't even have different case, or spaces. Is that because they have different tags or something?

Comment: @abarnert See the linked question. They could have extra white space that is trimmed when they are displayed, but are stored differently